# karaf - how to add environmental variable in system.properties file

Tags: java, locking, high-availability, karaf

I want to enable HA lock for Karaf. I would like to provide env variable value for some of the flag while enabling the lock. The flag which i need to update are as follows:
`karaf.lock.jdbc.clustername
karaf.lock.delay`

I tired giving below entry in `etc/system.properties` file but karaf took it as empty string

```
karaf.lock.jdbc.clustername=${APP_CLUSTER_NAME}
karaf.lock.delay=${LOCK_REFRESH}
```

where `APP_CLUSTER_NAME` and `LOCK_REFRESH` are environmental variables.

Even i tried define them in the **custom.properties** file as below,

```
LOCK_REFRESH=${env:LOCK_REFRESH}

APP_CLUSTER_NAME=${env:APP_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

This also not worked for me!

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways we can achieve this, what i did was,

1) Exported EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS as,

```
export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS="$EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS -Dapp.name=myApp"
```

then used the same in system.propeties file,

```
karaf.lock.jdbc.clustername=${app.name}
```

2) Even we can directly export the karaf varaible to EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS
     export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS="$EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS -Dkaraf.lock.jdbc.clustername=myApp"
       //i have not tried, it should work